# Bypass document scroll lock on one specific div JS (iOS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I use this code to lock whole document on position (on click event), it does exactly what I need for locking scroll, but now I need to allow scroll in one div, while whole document is locked as it is now. How do I do this with this code?

```js
    document.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); }, { passive: false });
```

Notes: Locked scroll position located NOT on top of the document.

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to the divs you want to keep scrolling and in your handler just check the target div to see if it contains or in the examples case doesn't contain the div before preventing the default behavior.

```js
    document.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) {
      if (!e.target.classList.contains('keep-moving')) e.preventDefault(); 
    }, { passive: false });
```

Comment: So, you are suggesting that I add div where I want to be able to scroll inside "keep-moving", and this div become an exception of not-to-scroll on body rule, correct? @Harry Chilinguerian

Comment: @AndrewK just add the class 'keep-moving' the name of the class is arbitrary, you can name it whatever you want, but check to see if that element is the target of your touchmove event.

Comment: As I said before, its not working, and I don't really get what you are trying to show me on JSFiddel, my case is the whole body is locked, not just one by one container, and I'm seeking for an answer how make one "child" container scrollable but keep restrains on all other part of a document (parent) same way as it is with my code above. If you answer is solving this somehow then I don't get it. Can you "elaborate" please by showing you solution with my remarks in Fiddel ? In your example the the **whole** document is scrollable (as on mobile as on desktop)  @Harry Chilinguerian

Comment: I am sorry it's not helpful, the div does scroll when the page doesn't on the jsfiddle I provided on an android device and an ios device.  I do see one issue where the page does scroll when the div reaches the end, but that can be fixed.  I'll see if I can adjust and fix it but not working isn't very descriptive and it works on my end.

Comment: Tested both on latest desktop and mobile Safari, I'm sorry if it sound ungrateful, but I am looking for solution for mobile (all, and especially iOS) and as I tested it on both JSFiddel and Codepen template, it seems like it doesn't work in this browsers at all @Harry Chilinguerian PS: to be specific on my previos comment: The entire document is scrollable, it doesn't matter class or no class assigned to the div.

Comment: Same in Chrome on MacOS @Harry Chilinguerian